# Android: Content Bubble Edittext Delete Bubble on Click

Tags: android

I have a MultiAutoCompleteTextView. I want to reach bubble right drawable onClick method.

This is my MultiAutoCompleteTextView class:

**TextViewClass.java**

```
public class TextViewClass extends MultiAutoCompleteTextView implements OnItemClickListener, TextWatcher{

Context ActivityContext;

LayoutInflater Inflater;

ArrayList<ItemContact> Contacts;

public TextViewClass(Context ActivityContext) {
    super(ActivityContext);
    init(ActivityContext);
}

public TextViewClass(Context ActivityContext, AttributeSet Attrs) {
    super(ActivityContext, Attrs);
    init(ActivityContext);
}

public TextViewClass(Context ActivityContext, AttributeSet Attrs, int DefStyle) {
    super(ActivityContext, Attrs, DefStyle);
    init(ActivityContext);
}

private void init(Context ActivityContext){
    this.ActivityContext = ActivityContext;
    this.Contacts = new ArrayList<ItemContact>();

    this.setThreshold(0);
    this.setTokenizer(new CommaTokenizer());

    this.addTextChangedListener(this);
    this.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    Inflater = (LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void addBubbles(String ContactName){
    SpannableStringBuilder SpannableBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(getText().toString().replace(",", " "));

    LayoutInflater Inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    TextView tvContacts = (TextView) Inflater.inflate(R.layout.chips_edittext, null);
    tvContacts.setText(ContactName);
    tvContacts.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.delete_contact, 0);

    // capture bitmapt of genreated textview
    int Spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    tvContacts.measure(Spec, Spec);
    tvContacts.layout(0, 0, tvContacts.getMeasuredWidth(), tvContacts.getMeasuredHeight());

    Bitmap ContactBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tvContacts.getWidth(), tvContacts.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas ContactCanvas = new Canvas(ContactBitmap);
    ContactCanvas.translate(-tvContacts.getScrollX(), -tvContacts.getScrollY());

    tvContacts.draw(ContactCanvas);
    tvContacts.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    Bitmap CacheBitmap = tvContacts.getDrawingCache();
    Bitmap ViewBitmap = CacheBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    tvContacts.destroyDrawingCache();

    BitmapDrawable BitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(ViewBitmap);
    BitmapDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, BitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), BitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

    ImageSpan Span = new ImageSpan(BitmapDrawable);
    SpannableBuilder.setSpan(Span, SpannableBuilder.length() - ContactName.length() - 1, SpannableBuilder.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    setText(SpannableBuilder);
    setSelection(getText().length());
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setBubbles(){
    SpannableStringBuilder SpannableBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(getText().toString());

    String Contacts[] = getText().toString().trim().split(",");
    int x = 0;

    if(Contacts.length > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < Contacts.length; i ++){
            if(!Contacts[i].equals("")){
                final String Contact = Contacts[i].toString();

                LayoutInflater Inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                TextView tvContacts = (TextView) Inflater.inflate(R.layout.chips_edittext, null);
                tvContacts.setText(Contact);
                tvContacts.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.delete_contact, 0);

                // capture bitmapt of genreated textview
                int Spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                tvContacts.measure(Spec, Spec);
                tvContacts.layout(0, 0, tvContacts.getMeasuredWidth(), tvContacts.getMeasuredHeight());

                Bitmap ContactBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(tvContacts.getWidth(), tvContacts.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas ContactCanvas = new Canvas(ContactBitmap);
                ContactCanvas.translate(-tvContacts.getScrollX(), -tvContacts.getScrollY());

                tvContacts.draw(ContactCanvas);
                tvContacts.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

                Bitmap CacheBitmap = tvContacts.getDrawingCache();
                Bitmap ViewBitmap = CacheBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

                tvContacts.destroyDrawingCache();

                BitmapDrawable BitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(ViewBitmap);
                BitmapDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, BitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), BitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

                ImageSpan Span = new ImageSpan(BitmapDrawable);
                SpannableBuilder.setSpan(Span, x, x + Contact.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                x = x + Contact.length() + 1;
            } else {
                x = x + 1;
            }
        }

        setText(SpannableBuilder);
        setSelection(getText().length());
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence CSequence, int Start, int Count, int After) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence CSequence, int Start, int Before, int Count) {
    if(Count > 0)
        if(CSequence.charAt(Start) == ',')
            setBubbles();
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable Edit) {

}
```

I want to delete bubble with click ımage;

[image: I want to]

I have researched, and a find **ClickableSpan**, but I doesn't the set this code.. Please help me..

Comment: Did u find how to use clickablespan..? Pls share the code if you know..

Comment: May be you can add two items. One Content Bubble EditText and the second a image with drawable (ImageView). Place the two elements together without padding and without margin.

Comment: you can set drawable right icon, a cross and can set click listener on it. There are lots of library codes available on net. Search it using CHIP library